# Beacon API Cannot load <url> due to access control checks when navigating to new page

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a `navigation.sendBeacon` request being sent during a pagehide event on Safari with some analytics data to an endpoint on the same domain as the current page. This works fine when the tab is being closed, but when navigating to a new url, Safari throws `Beacon API Cannot load <url> due to access control checks` while trying to make the request.

This issue does not occur on Chrome, and there are no other logs shown. I don't think this is a CORS request, all domains and subdomains are the same.

Has anyone else seen this or know how to fix?

Comment: HI, I am also facing same issues in safari browser, can any one let me know the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: @RyanCheu I am encountering the same issue.
any workarounds / fixes / relevant info you;v learned ?
is it a confirmed bug that was not yet filed on the webkit bug system ?

Comment: @OrenM I wasn't able to work around this, it'd probably be good to file a bug.

Comment: @RyanCheu did you file a bug? If so can you link to it here? Note: this is definitely *not* a CORS issue because I run `sendBeacon()` just fine in situation where the page is not unloading.

Comment: I did not file a bug, but still think it'd be great if someone else did

Comment: Filed: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188329

Answer (score 2):

Using any sort of Asynchronous HTTP request, whether it is sendBeacon, fetch, or XMLHttpRequest seems to have problems in both desktop and iOS Safari at the moment when inside a pagehide event. I have received versions of the same error such as `Fetch API cannot load ... due to access control checks` when I use different types of HTTP requesters within the pagehide event. I am sure that it is not a CORS error, since the exact same request does not have a problem outside of a pagehide event.

While not recommended due the its blocking of the main thread, I am using synchronous requests until the bug is patched in Safari. For my use case, it is more critical that the analytics data from pagehide is successfully sent even even though it causes a small delay to the end user. Synchronous HTTP requests are a meh workaround until the bug is remediated, which hopefully is soon since the link from @Phillip Walton suggests that a patch has been accepted but obviously has not been released yet.

```
if (isSafari && pageHideBroken) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false, //The most important line
        url: `https://`,
        data: 'Goodbye',
        timeout: 5000
                });
}
else {
    navigator.sendBeacon(`https://`, 'Goodbye');
}
```

I have confirmed that on both Desktop Safari and iOS Safari that my backend successfully receives the data using this approach. JQuery is not required to make a sync HTTP request, but I just used `$.ajax` as the example due to its conciseness compared to XMLHttpRequest. If you make this workaround conditional like I have, then it is easy to swap back to navigator.sendBeacon once the bug is fixed! This type of browser-dependent behavior is never fun to code around.